# List View not reloaded

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I encountered a bug on ICS . Using a ListView and changing the adapter over time, I don't see any change to the content of the listView until I scroll down and then return to the top.
I used these commands to notify the changes to the adapter :

```
adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
adap.notifyDataSetInvalidated();//added just to see if it solved... but it didn't resolve
```

In Gingerbread the code works perfectly.

Comment: are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in your main thread i.e your UI thread?

Comment: Also create a new adapter each time when you populate the `ListView` like `adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(
           SearchAssetActivity.this, itemList);
         lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Ok, re-create the ListView works... but why notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work?

PS: I call it in the UI thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also create a new adapter each time when you populate the ListView like this:

```
adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(SearchAssetActivity.this, itemList);
lview3.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And as far as why `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work.Please go through this. Even I faced similar issue.

[notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3669325/840520)